# Update the value of a field in a JSON object using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, string

I have a JSON object:

```
 [{"file":"post_files/feb641027629b6a7ba78fb47063c6763vid.flv","title":"Sample"},
  {"file":"post_files/74c73cf0e28d6ca431ab4c2e2299f39fbarsandtone.flv","title":"Bars"}]
```

As you can see, `file` fields have values like `post_file/feb.................flv`.

All I want is to append `http://divinotech.in/` to all the `file` fields' values, i.e. the value should get edited like this:

```
http://divinotech.in/post_file/feb.................flv
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This is either a JSON string or an array of objects. A JSON object is something completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop through the elements of the array and modify the `file` property:

```
var array = [
    { "file": "post_files/feb641027629b6a7ba78fb47063c6763vid.flv", "title":"Sample"}, 
    { "file": "post_files/74c73cf0e28d6ca431ab4c2e2299f39fbarsandtone.flv", "title":"Bars"}
];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].file = 'http://divinotech.in/' + array[i].file;
}

// at this stage the array will contain the desired values
```

And here's a [`live demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/9dvy4/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var result=[{"file":"post_files/feb641027629b6a7ba78fb47063c6763vid.flv","title":"Sample"},
  {"file":"post_files/74c73cf0e28d6ca431ab4c2e2299f39fbarsandtone.flv","title":"Bars"}]
for (var i in result) {
$("body").append('<a href="http://divinotech.in/'+result[i].file+'">'+result[i].title+'</a></br>');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9LCdw/6/)